My domain IP is redirected to Tilda's IP, not to my server
I have a website with a domain and had a website on Tilda. Then the domain was removed from Tilda, all domain records were erased, but it turned out that when I launch a self-written website, a Tilda plaque appears on my domain" Domain has been assigned. Please go to the site settings and put the domain name in the Domain tab."
I tried writing to Tilda support, they say that they have nothing tied, I also watched nslookup, it redirects to their ip, not my server. I tried to disable the firewall, looked at whether the ports were open. My site works every other time, then everything is fine, but when you rebuild the docker image, it redirects back to the Tilda. There are no errors in the nginx configuration, since another site is hanging with the same configuration. Also, this is not a host problem, since I contacted the server support, they said that everything was fine with them. Also, when I look through a web proxy, everything is fine, it would seem that this is a cache, but it was not there! Other users just have their old IP cached and need it to be displayed normally. I've tried everything, please help me!

Sorry, it's a bit unclear where the domain is now since you mentioned it's been removed. Do you still own the domain?

@sykez yes, I do. Domain was removed from Tilda so far. The domain is currently running and linked to the server


it redirects to their ip, not my server

Looks like it's pointing to a server which wasn't configured for your domain, so the record needs to be updated. I suggest to get your domain issue fixed with Tilda, take back the control of your domain and update your A record to your server accordingly.

I repeat, there is no any records of my domain in Tilda. My A record is right and linked to server. From time to time connection refused and redirected to Tilda's IP

@Photonik I'm assuming your DNS records are now managed somewhere, with clear visibility of all your records, and there is only one record for the hostname pointing to your server IP?
As long as nslookup returns Tilda IP, there's something wrong around DNS. As for cache, usually it's the TTL, but it should've been expired by now. Also try setting your local DNS to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8. See if it improves anything.
